# PhoneGap config.xml file

Tags: android, ios, xml, config, phonegap

I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.xyz.xyz"
        version   = "1.0.0">
    <name>Qwerty</name>
    <description>Your personal qwerty.</description>    
    <author href="https://qwerty.com" email="qwerty@qwerty.com">Qwery</author>
    <allow-navigation href="https://qwerty/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://xyz/*" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />     
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform> 
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" spec="1.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="2.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" spec="1.0.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="1.0.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" spec="2.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.2" />
</widget>
```

The PhoneGap build console says:
App ID  xxxx

Version 1.0.0

Owned by xxxx

PhoneGap (iOS / Android / Windows) cli-6.5.0 (4.3.1 / 6.1.2 / 4.4.3)

Source .zip package

But there is nothing in my code that indicates PhoneGap (iOS / Android / Windows) cli-6.5.0.

There is also a notice on the PhoneGap build console: cli-8.0.0 is now on PhoneGap Build

I tried to add

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.0.0" />
```

But that corrupted the iOS build.

1. How can I force cli-8.0.0 so that it works on both Android & iOS?
2. I have been looking for a COMPLETE config.xml example (for both iOS & Android) but can only find fragments?

Comment: Can you put error from error log?

Comment: Check this out: [phonegap cli](https://blog.phonegap.com/phonegap-7-0-1-now-on-build-and-it-includes-some-important-changes-89087fe465f5)

Comment: It worked, no more corrupt APKs from PhoneGap Build.